# does union or union all make a big difference?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a code that works,

```
CURSOR c_val IS
    SELECT 'Percentage' destype,
           1 descode
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL               --16028 change from union to union all for better performance 
    SELECT 'Unit'destype,
           2 descode
    FROM dual
    ORDER  BY descode DESC;
 --
```

i change the union to union all, from what i have read it wouldnt make a big differnece as long as i have a order by (which i do) , is this truth or should i just leave it the way it was , it still works both ways

Comment: The UNION removes duplicates and UNION ALL returns all rows so it really depends on what you need from your query.

Comment: In this case it's impossible that there be duplicates so you should use a UNION ALL so that there's no need for Oracle to attempt to de-duplicate.

Comment: @ben why do you say its impossible that there be duplicates ?

Comment: Because you only have two rows and they have different data.

Comment: The general rule is use `UNION ALL` - if you don't know whether to use `UNION ALL` or `UNION` then you should be using `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The choice between UNION and UNION ALL is not whether one of them works or not, or whether one of them is faster performing, but which one is correct for the logic you want to implement.

UNION ALL is simply the results of the two queries combined into a single result set. You should consider the order of the result sets to be random, although in practice you'd *probably* find that it's the first result set followed by the second.

UNION is the same, but with a DISTINCT applied to the combined sets. Therefore it's possible for it to return fewer rows and take longer and consume more resources. You would probably find that the order of rows is different, but again you should assume that the order is random.

Applying an ORDER BY to either one of them is the only way to guarantee an order on the result set. It would affect performance of the UNION ALL, but may not affect UNION too much (on top of the impact of the DISTINCT) because the optimiser might choose a DISTINCT implementation that will return an ordered result set.

So in your case you want both rows to appear (and in fact UNION would not eliminate either of them), and you want the order to be specified -- so based on that, UNION ALL and the ORDER BY you have provided are the correct approaches.

Answer (score 2):

```
"UNION" = "UNION ALL" + "DISTINCT"
```

So basically by going for `UNION ALL` you save a dedup operation. In this case you may find that the performance gain is negligible but it can be important on large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Union All returns all rows, so you might get duplicates. Union is effectively like a distinct. In your case, it doesn't make a difference as you are using the same tables!

Comment: so which one would you recommend?

Comment: Use the one you need.